# Suppress Default Completions in Sublime Text 3 Plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm experimenting with creating an completion file in Sublime Text 3. I've created a file called `my_css_completions.py` and placed it in `Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`. It contains this.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


properties = {
    'foo',
    'bar',
}

class CSSCompletions(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        if not view.match_selector(locations[0], 'source.css'):
            print('not css')
            return []

        completions = []
        for prop in properties:
                completions.append((prop, prop+': $1;'))

        return (completions, sublime.INHIBIT_WORD_COMPLETIONS | sublime.INHIBIT_EXPLICIT_COMPLETIONS)
```

I've been trying to get `my_css_completions.py` to override or suppress the default completions, but instead what happens is that my completions get added along side the default completions. Is there some way to only get my completions to show up in CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Packages are just archives containing all the files of that package. Sublime Text allows you to override individual files, replacing their default behaviour. (Though not individual completions, for that, I recommend copying the completions file and only changing those that you want changed

To do that, You just need a file with the same name and relative path as the one you want to replace, only that it's relative to your settings directory, not the install directory. So if I want to replace the python "for"-snippet on Windows, I create a new file

```
%appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Python\Snippets\for.sublime-snippet
```

The Package "PackageResourceViewer" is a great helper. Using the "PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource"-command, you can browse through packages, open any files you need and upon saving them they will automatically be saved to the correct location to overwrite the default files.